# Apache POI - How to retrieve "rect" object inside "pict" object

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to convert a Word document to HTML using Apache POI. I have a Word document that has a horizontal line after a paragraph. The OOXML for the horizontal line looks like this:

```
          <w:p w14:paraId="721E1052" w14:textId="05637367" w:rsidR="002D1248" w:rsidRPr="00BB3E82" w:rsidRDefault="00B3113F" w:rsidP="00797596">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Courier New"/>
                <w:snapToGrid w:val="0"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                <w:lang w:eastAsia="fi-FI"/>
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Courier New"/>
                <w:snapToGrid w:val="0"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                <w:lang w:eastAsia="fi-FI"/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:pict w14:anchorId="534EEFD0">
                <v:rect id="_x0000_i1025" style="width:0;height:1.5pt" o:hralign="center" o:hrstd="t" o:hr="t" fillcolor="#a0a0a0" stroked="f"/>
              </w:pict>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
```

Corresponding to this horizontal line, I want to add a HR tag in HTML. However, I am not able to retrieve the "rect" element inside "pict". This is what I have tried so far:

```
List<org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture> pics = run.getCTR().getPictList();
        if(pics!=null) {
            log.debug("Size of pics = "+pics.size());
            for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture pic : pics) {
                Node picNode = pic.getDomNode();
                CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.parse(picNode);
                if(ctGroup!=null) {
                    log.debug("Size of rects= "+ctGroup.getRectList().size());
                }
            }
```

The above code gives:
Size of pics = 1
Size of rects= 0
I am not sure why that is the case. Any help in understanding how to retrieve the "rect" object would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parse a `com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup` element from a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture` dom node.

But all `ooxml-schemas` objects inherit from `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject`. So they can select children by element URI and element local name using [XmlObject.selectChildren](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html#selectChildren(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). What we need to know is that the name space URI for `com.microsoft.schemas.vml.*` is "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml".

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

import java.util.List;

public class WordReadCTPictureContent {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./HRBetweenParagraphs.docx";

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));

  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {

    List<org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture> pics = run.getCTR().getPictList();
    System.out.println("Size of pics = " + pics.size());
    for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture pic : pics) {
     //select com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect children by elementUri and elementLocalName
     XmlObject[] rects = pic.selectChildren("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml", "rect");
     System.out.println("Count of rects = " + rects.length);
     for (XmlObject obj : rects) {
      com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect rect = (com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect)obj;
      //now we can work with found com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect
      System.out.println("Id of found rect = " + rect.getId());
     }

    }

   }
  }

  document.close();
 }

}
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much Axel. As always, your responses are so much helpful and perfect. Thank you again!